# google drive file.list query returns false for sub-folder ID - php

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I'm able to list the items present in a folder located in root of google drive using the following function. but when I try to list items in a sub-folder located inside a parent folder (parent folder is in root of google drive)

```
[PARENT FOLDER] //the 'sub folder' and 'other files' are getting listed
       └------[SUB FOLDER] //query is returned false when i try to put this folder ID as parent
       |            └--------[FILE LOCATED INSIDE SUB FOLDER]
       └------[OTHER FILES]
```

Function used to list files from google drive:

```
function listFilesFolders($client, $search, $subFolderId){

        $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

        //ID of the folder located in root of google drive
        //works fine if i run the query with this ID
        $superParentId = '1Xky058b134vadgSOyD-ADFagaGAGAdgha'; 

        //properly working query
        //$query = "'".$superParentId."' in parents and trashed = false"; 

        //query that runs for the subfolder located inside the parent folder ($superParentId)
        $query = "'".$subFolderId."' in parents and trashed = false"; 

        $optParams = array('q' => $query);

        // Returns the list of files and folders as object
        $results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

        // Return false if nothing is found
        if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        // Converting array to object
        $result = array();
        foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
            $result[$file->getId()] = $file->getName();
        }

        return $result;
}
```

May I know how to list files located in the sub folder?

Thanks,

Comment: your method needs to be recursive and call itself with the new sub folder.

Comment: I'm stuck in that part of choosing parent folder and then running the query with sub folder ID (recursive). Could you please mention with a code snippet?

Comment: You would need something like this listFilesFolders($client, $search, $file->getId) but i suggest checking that its actually a folder  first.  check the file type it will tell you if its a folder.  Sorry the only sample of have for this is in C# and i dont have the time to make a sample in php right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things

1. Find out which of the files in your super parent folder are subfolders
   You can do it with a modified query:

```
$query2 = "'$superParentId' in parents and trashed = false and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'";
...
```

2. List the files contained in those subfolders in a loop

```
...
$query3 = "'$subFolderId' in parents and trashed = false";
...
```

Comment: Hi do I need to run `$service->files->listFiles($optParams)` with sub folder ID inside the for each loop grabbed from query that has 'SuperParentID'?

Comment: I'm able to get the subFolderID inside the function as parameter.. when O run using the parameter. It returns false.

Comment: Exactly, when you run the query with the 'SuperParentID' and `mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'`, you will obtain an array with potentially several subfolders. So you need to loop through those subfolders and listFiles for each of those subfolders.

Comment: Before you implement it in PHP, I recommend you to experiment with Try this API https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list with different queries https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files

Comment: Hi I'm still getting false when i run another query within the foreach loop after getting the subFolderId. It seems `in parents` doesn't work with sub folder IDs. I tried changing the folder permissions, but nothing works.

Comment: Hi, I figured out the issue. I was using the scope `drive.file`. which lists only the file created by my app. the contents of the subfolder are uploaded directly from google drive. that is why it didn't get listed in the loop. The correct scope to use is to use `drive` scope.

Comment: Yes, the scopes are very important. You can see the meaning of different scopes here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-auth